# Writing test-case for RN component to see if doesn't crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing

I have never written test cases.

I am building a RN native component and I want to write a test case to make sure

- it works on the previous version
- it works on current version before I publish it.

Now, I googled and the only thing I was able to find out was snapshot based testing for React native using jest but that isn't something I case about (the goal here is to make sure that the component doesn't throw error if I update dev or peer dependency)

Any idea on how can I do it? My component should be something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-input)